# ip address range of the google.com to configure firewall

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ip, firewall, nslookup

I would like to know the ip range of the google.com to configure firewalls. I found this article https://support.google.com/a/answer/60764?hl=en but it doesnot help either. How can i find complete list of google ips?

nslookup returns the followin information.

```
$ nslookup -q=TXT google.com 8.8.8.8
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
google.com      text = "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

Comment: See this..... http://snurps.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-many-ip-addresses-does-google-have.html

Comment: Also see this users answer... http://stackoverflow.com/a/16187724

Comment: OP, couldn't you just use google's static IP (172.217.0.46)?